# How to code a vectorized expression that depends on other vectorized expression?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

If for example I have three expressions: `A`, `B` and `C` as follows:

```
A(i+1) = A(i) + C(i).k
B(i+1) = B(i) + A(i).h
C(i+1) = A(i) + B(i)
```

where `k` and `h` are some constants and `m` and `n` is the desired size of `C`. `i` is the previous obtained value, `i+1` is the next value. Now, if I use `for` loop, then I can code it as:

```
A(1)= 2;
B(1)= 5;
C(1)= 3;
for i=1:10
    A(i+1) = A(i) + C(i)*2;
    B(i+1) = B(i) + A(i)*3;
    C(i+1) = A(i) + B(i);
end
```

And it works just fine. But I want to code it in a **vector form**, as in without having to use a loop. But the problem is I do not know how to get around the dependency of:

- `A` on its previous value and previous `C` value
- `B` on it previous values and previous `C` value of `A`
- `C` on the previous values of `A` and `B`

Comment: If it depedns on the previous value, you cant vectorize :(

Comment: Oh really. @AnderBiguri that is sad.

Comment: Can't we use handles or functions? @AnderBiguri

Comment: Vectorization is a way of computin "everything at once", you cant do that if a value depends on the previous values. just make a for loop, thay are not *that* bad

Comment: The thing is I am working on large data and using **for loop** takes days. I am trying to figure a way around to speed up the code. I already have a 16 Gb Ram and a 64 bit windows.

Comment: Again, most likely the for loop is not that a bad idea. In the latest versions of MATLAB for loops are decently fast. You are not going to get a huge improvement if you could do it, but you cant. You need to find some other way of speeding up, or deal with it!

Comment: Note taht what you are trying to compute is a linear homogenous recurrence relation. These can be explicitly solved. No need for using for loops.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I am prepared to deal with it. But thought of giving it a try.

Comment: @flawr I am sorry but could you elaborate more.

Comment: First of all, make sure you preallocate `A`, `B`, `C`...

Comment: @nashynash I'm going to do that in a moment. First note that preallocation is usefull to. Write `A=zeros(1,11);B=zeros(1,11);C=zeros(1,11)` in front of the loop (replace 11 with the number of entries you need for the `for` loop.)

Comment: @Dev-iL Oh yes I am aware of the preallocation and have used it in the actual code. For some reason I thought it wouldn't be necessary to show that here.

Comment: @flawr okay. I am waiting.

Comment: Whenever programming cant improve things-> use maths!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a matrix-based way to obtain the `n`-th value of the `[A;B;C]` vector. I wouldn't exactly call it vectorization, but this could speed things up considerably for you:

```
[A,B,C] = deal(zeros(11,1));
A(1)= 2;
B(1)= 5;
C(1)= 3;

%% // Original method
for k=1:10
  A(k+1) = A(k) + C(k)*2;
  B(k+1) = B(k) + A(k)*3;
  C(k+1) = A(k) + B(k);
end

%% // Matrix method:
%// [ A ]     [1  0  2][ A ]
%// | B |  =  |3  1  0|| B |
%// [ C ]     [1  1  0][ C ]
%//      i+1                i
%// 
%// [ A ]     [1  0  2][ A ]        [1  0  2]   ( [1  0  2][ A ] )
%// | B |  =  |3  1  0|| B |    =   |3  1  0| * ( |3  1  0|| B | )
%// [ C ]     [1  1  0][ C ]        [1  1  0]   ( [1  1  0][ C ] )
%//      i+2                i+1                                 i

%// Thus, this coefficient matrix taken to the n-th power, multiplied by the input 
%// vector will yield the values of A(n+1), B(n+1), and C(n+1):
M = [1 0 2
     3 1 0
     1 1 0];
isequal(M^10*[A(1);B(1);C(1)],[A(11);B(11);C(11)])
```

In reality you can use `M` to the appropriate power (positive or negative) to obtain any `[A,B,C]`<sub>n</sub> from any `[A,B,C]`<sub>k</sub> ...

Comment: I am sorry. I tried running the code you posted. I don't seem to get the desired result. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nashynash That depends what the "desired result" is (you only mentioned that you want to vectorize the code, not what values you actually need). __Please notice the last line of code__: if you want to get the full length of the vectors (1...n) then this method isn't (currently, without `bsxfun`) good for you. If, however, you're only interested in the `n+1`-th values - you can use it.

Comment: Ah I see. Now I get it. I need to get the full length so it won't do me any good. But anyways it will be useful for some other day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In addition to this, if the eigenvalues of `M` are distinct, you can find the [eigendecomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EigenDecomposition.html) `M = P*D*inv(P)` for diagonal `D`, then `M^n = P*(D^n)*inv(P)`. Expand this to get explicit expressions for `A(n)`, `B(n)` and `C(n)`.

Comment: @Steve - I believe this is what [flawr did in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35035540/3372061)...

Answer (score 5):

First, forgive me for abusing Matlab syntax for expressing mathematical stuff.

Consider following code, where we do exactly the same as in your example. Note that `A,B,C` are the rows of `X`.

```
X = zeros(3,N+1);
X(:,1) = [2,5,3];
M= [1,0,2;3,1,0;1,1,0];
for i=1:N
X(:,i+1) = M*X(:,i);
end
```

This is just a matrix vector notation of the above code. I think it is even slower. Note that we could also compute: `X(:,i+1) = M^i * X(:,1)` which is even slower.

Notice that we can use the eigenvalue decomposition:

```
[V,D] = eigs(M);
X(:,i+1) = [V*D*inv(V)]^i * X;
```

Therefore

```
X(:,i+1) = V*D^i*inv(V) * X;
```

So `V*D^i*inv(V)` is an explicit formula for the `i+1`th term of `X`. I suggest computing those analytically, and plug the formula you get into your code again.

EDIT: I wrote some code that should be close to analyitcally solving the system, you can compare the runtimes. It seems in the end preallocation with your first method is still the fastest *IF* you need *ALL* the terms. If you only need one of them, my suggested method is certainly quicker.

```
clear;clc
N = 10000000;
tic
    A(1)= 2;
    B(1)= 5;
    C(1)= 3;
    A = zeros(1,N+1);
    B=A;C=A;
    for i=1:N
    A(i+1) = A(i) + C(i)*2;
    B(i+1) = B(i) + A(i)*3;
    C(i+1) = A(i) + B(i);
    end
toc

tic
    X = zeros(3,N+1);
    X(:,1) = [2,5,3];
    M= [1,0,2;3,1,0;1,1,0];
    for i=1:N
    X(:,i+1) = M*X(:,i);
    end
toc



tic
    M= [1,0,2;3,1,0;1,1,0];
    [V,D]=eig(M); 
    v=0:N;
    d=diag(D);
    B=bsxfun(@power,repmat(d,1,N+1),v);
    Y=bsxfun(@times,V * B, V \[2;5;3]);
toc


tic
    M= [1,0,2;3,1,0;1,1,0];
    [V,D]=eig(M); 
    v=0:N;
    d=diag(D);
    Y = ones(3,N+1);
    for i=1:N
    Y(:,i+1) = d.*Y(:,i);
    end
    Y=bsxfun(@times,V * B, V \[2;5;3]);
toc
```

Comment: You say that the first method is slower but the second is too mathematical.  Anyway,thanks for the pointers. Will look up on EVD.