# construct block matrix consisting of different powers of basis matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Assuming that we have a basis matrix `A`

```
>> A = [1,2;-1,3]
A =

   1   2
  -1   3
```

I am wondering if there is an easy command that can construct a block matrix consisting of `A`, `A^2`, `A^3` ... `A^n` with any given positive integer `n`, like

```
B = [A; A^2; A^3; ...; A^n]
```

Evidently, if `A` is a scalar, we can do like `A.^(1:n)`. I was wondering if there is a similar manipulation or some command for matrix `A`. That's my motivation.

I can make it with loops (`for` loop or `arrayfun`) but I am looking for some easy and elegant command for it.

Comment: Do you want matrix exponent, or elementwise exponents?

Comment: @AnderBiguri matrix exponent

Comment: Relevant Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034584. In the case of a small matrix such as 2x2 it might be possible to come up with an equation for each of the entries for any `n`.

Comment: Another related post on math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301000/

Comment: Is A always 2*2?

Comment: @Wolfie Nope, `A` could be a square matrix of any size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a recursive method, maybe the following could be an option

```
function y = f(A,n)
  if n==1 
    y = A;
    return;
  end 
  y = [A;f(A,n-1)*kron(eye(n-1),A)];
end
```

then

```
B =

    1    2
   -1    3
   -1    8
   -4    7
   -9   22
  -11   13
  -31   48
  -24   17
  -79   82
  -41    3
```

Answer (score 3):

Super verbose way of doing it in one line:

```
B= cell2mat(cellfun(@mpower,mat2cell(repmat(A,n,1),[ones(n,1)*size(A,1)],size(A,2)),mat2cell([1:n]',ones(n,1),1),'UniformOutput',false))
```

However, I think a for loop (with preallocation) is likely faster and much, much clearer. A for loop is not "inellegant" if its clear. Clarity should be your goal, unless its speed is super critical (and again, this one-liner still does loops under the hood).

I'm sure someone will come up with a clearer one liner, yet my comments will still apply.

PD: The magician @LuisMendo proposes: `B=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k){A^k},1:n).')` as a much cleaner option. (Still loops inside)

Comment: Not really easy, nor elegant, and probably slow due to the usage of cells. Otherwise, kudos for finding a one-liner!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I used `arrayfun` to construct the matrix, but I guess it is kind of hidden loop. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding The premise of your request is not valid, I think. There is no real reason to avoid loops, unless they are less clear. (e.g. instead of sum)

Comment: If `A` is a scalar, we can do like `A.^(1:n)`. I was wondering if there is a similar manipulation or some command for matrix `A`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding no, because `.^` and `^` are completely different MATLAB functions. You can do what you propose only because its an elementwise operator, not because its a "power".

Comment: Well, I know the difference between `.^` and `^`. I am just curious if there is an simple operation that can work on matrix `A` to obtain a series of matrix powers.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily an answer either, since it also relies on cellfun, and similar in spirit to other answers here, but I think this is slightly more elegant, and makes use of a built-in rather than an anonymous function (which is guaranteed to be faster, if that matters at all to you).

Also, this version is generalised for a matrix of exponents of any shape, producing the appropriate "block" output.

```
A = [ 1,2
     -1,3 ];

N = [ 1,2,3
      2,3,4
      3,4,5 ];

expblk = @(A,N) cell2mat(
             cellfun( @mpower, {A}, num2cell(N), 'UniformOutput', false )
         );

expblk(A,N)

% ans =
%     1    2   -1    8   -9   22
%    -1    3   -4    7  -11   13
%    -1    8   -9   22  -31   48
%    -4    7  -11   13  -24   17
%    -9   22  -31   48  -79   82
%   -11   13  -24   17  -41    3
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case the matrix A is diagonalizable, you get an easy solution (not a one-liner, but still!) :

```
[V,D] = eig(A);
k = size(A,1);
B = kron(eye(n),V)*(reshape(D.^reshape(1:n,[1 1 n]),[k k*n]).')*inv(V);
```

Taken from the [basic theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1536840/87652). Beside this solution in specific cases, I don't think that the general form involving Jordan's form is easy to implement in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

[`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) can be helpful:

```
A = [1,2;-1,3];
n = 3;
B = eval(['[A' sprintf(';A^%d',2:n) ']']);
```

However using a loop to multiply the matrix by itself is efficient specially when the matrix is large.

```
C = cell (n,1);
D = 1;
for k = 1:n
    D *= A; % In MATLAB use D = D * A;
    C{k} = D;
end
B = vertcat(C{:});
```

And its `eval` version  in Octave syntax (for fun and not recommended):

```
B = eval(['[D=A' repmat(';D*=A',1,n-1) ']']);
```

Comment: Mhm, you might want to give a big warning about the pitfalls of `eval`. Even its documentation page has that warning prominently on top. Also I doubt this will be any faster, due to the disabling of the JIT when using `eval`.

Comment: @Adriaan I'm very very sorry! I was forced  by the question to use eval, otherwise I would'nt have done it.

Comment: I want to +1 for the loop version, which is likely much more efficient than OP's original loop (computing each of the powers individually). But the `eval` solution... If you had posted two separate answers I could have upvoted one and downvoted the other! :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. eval has its drawbacks but in this answer it shows different way of thinking that may be eligible for upvotes. I can see something strange. The question  needs a loop free answer but most of the answers contain loop!!  If you are in doubt I think that I have convinced you to do upvote.  Thanks in advance.!